# Why is my mac calling my samba share "Sharepoint"?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, network-shares, samba

When I connect to a samba share running on ubuntu 10.04, the mac reports the type as "Sharepoint"?

Is there a way to configure this?

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: An intense dislike of Sharepoint?

Comment: @quack - is it appropriate to remove the sharepoint tag from here since it is misleading? Sharepoint is just the term Apple uses to define a file share, most people looking at it in a tag would assume it's about Microsoft Sharepoint.

Comment: @markm: thanks, i'm not familiar enough with OSX to have realized that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "sharepoint" (sometimes "share point" or "share-point") has been used in discussions of file sharing protocols since before Microsoft named their collaboration server product that.

The term is roughly synonymous with "share", or "shared folder", or "shared directory", but it puts a little more emphasis on the server-side view of things: The server has a large filesystem hierarchy, possibly spread across multiple disk partitions (volumes), and only some of the subtrees of the filesystem are shared. So each directory that's the root of a share is the "sharepoint" within the server's filesystem.

This is a counterpoint (heh) to the Unix concept of a "mount point", which is the point (directory) in the overall filesystem where a separate volume's filesystem is mounted.

Answer (score 0):

> Source: http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20031022164821984
>
> SAMBA sharepoints and standard Windows
>   "shared directories" work in almost
>   exactly the same way as AFP shares.
>   The only difference is the URL that
>   you use. If you want to dynamically
>   mount a Windows (or SAMBA) sharepoint,
>   follow the directions at Mike's site
>   for a regular AFP Dynamic mount and
>   replace the URL value with:
>
> ```
> url==smb://username:password@servername/sharepoint
> ```
>
> Where servername is either the IP
>   address, hostname, or fully-qualified
>   hostname (foo.example.com) of the
>   machine that you would like to connect
>   to, and where sharepoint is the shared
>   directory that you would like to
>   connect to.
>
> In some cases, depending on the
>   configuration of your network, this
>   may not work. If that happens to you,
>   try:
>
> ```
> url==smb://Username:Password@Workgroup/servername/sharepoint
> ```